# The site can't be reached when launching a website through AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, http

Hello I recently bought a udemy course on the basics of AWS. In one of the labs I had to make a web page that reads hello world but I keep getting site is unreachable, I've tried this on google chrome, firefox and edge but it keeps giving me the site is unreachable. Here is the script for my webpage which the instructor gave us.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo su

yum update -y

yum install httpd -y

chkconfig httpd on

systemctl start httpd

cd /var/www/html

echo $HOSTNAME "<h1>Hello there from US-EAST-1a !<h1>" > index.html
```

For inbound rules I have both HTTP, TCP protocol, port 80, source 0.0.0.0/0 & ::/0. I even tried including HTTPS, TCP protocol port 443 with source 0.0.0.0/0 & ::/0 but I still get the same error

Comment: Are you accessing the site via it's public ip? is apache running? (`systemctl status httpd`)

Comment: Ssh to the instance and verity that `curl localhost` works. Then you need to provide other details of your instance. Does it have public IP? Is it in public subnet? What about any network ACLs?